# my extension of kivy library is installed but not import in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, kivy

I installed extension `kivy` in `VScode` but kivy does not import in code. When I write import then there is no option kivy.

I want to import kivy extension in VScode.

Error is below:

```
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [11 lines of output]
      DEPRECATION: --no-binary currently disables reading from the cache of locally built wheels. In the future --no-binary 
will not influence the wheel cache. pip 23.1 will enforce this behaviour change. A possible replacement is to use the --no-cache-dir option. You can use the flag --use-feature=no-binary-enable-wheel-cache to test the upcoming behaviour. Discussion 
can be found at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/11453
      Collecting setuptools
        Using cached setuptools-65.6.3-py3-none-any.whl (1.2 MB)
      Collecting wheel
        Using cached wheel-0.38.4-py3-none-any.whl (36 kB)
      Collecting cython!=0.27,!=0.27.2,<=0.29.28,>=0.24
        Using cached Cython-0.29.28-py2.py3-none-any.whl (983 kB)
      Collecting kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev~=0.3.3
        Using cached kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev-0.3.3-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (3.9 MB)
      ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement kivy_deps.sdl2_dev~=0.4.5 (from versions: 0.5.1)       
      ERROR: No matching distribution found for kivy_deps.sdl2_dev~=0.4.5
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your python version.

According to [the document of kivy](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/gettingstarted/installation.html), `Kivy` 2.1.0 officially supports Python versions 3.7 - 3.10.

Please try to use **python 3.7 - 3.10**.